# Embedding several inset axes in another axis using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

Is it possible to embed a changing number of plots in a matplotlib axis? For example, the `inset_axes` method is used to place inset axes inside parent axes:

[image]

However, I have several rows of plots and I want to include some inset axes inside the last axis object of each row.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,4, figsize=(15,15))
for i in range(2):
    ax[i][0].plot(np.random.random(40))
    ax[i][2].plot(np.random.random(40))
    ax[i][3].plot(np.random.random(40))

    # number of inset axes
    number_inset = 5
    for j in range(number_inset):
        ax[i][4].plot(np.random.random(40))
```

[image]

Here instead of the 5 plots drawn in the last column, I want several inset axes containing a plot. Something like this:

[image]

The reason for this is that every row refers to a different item to be plotted and the last column is supposed to contain the components of such item. Is there a way to do this in matplotlib or maybe an alternative way to visualize this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to use `inset_axes`? What about adding the small axes to the figure directly (e.g. with [`GridSpec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @hitzg mentioned, the most common way to accomplish something like this is to use `GridSpec`.  `GridSpec` creates an imaginary grid object that you can slice to produce subplots.  It's an easy way to align fairly complex layouts that you want to follow a regular grid.

However, it may not be immediately obvious how to use it in this case.  You'll need to create a `GridSpec` with `numrows * numinsets` rows by `numcols` columns and then create the "main" axes by slicing it with intervals of `numinsets`.

In the example below (2 rows, 4 columns, 3 insets), we'd slice by `gs[:3, 0]` to get the upper left "main" axes, `gs[3:, 0]` to get the lower left "main" axes, `gs[:3, 1]` to get the next upper axes, etc.  For the insets, each one is `gs[i, -1]`.

As a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def build_axes_with_insets(numrows, numcols, numinsets, **kwargs):
    """
    Makes a *numrows* x *numcols* grid of subplots with *numinsets* subplots
    embedded as "sub-rows" in the last column of each row.

    Returns a figure object and a *numrows* x *numcols* object ndarray where
    all but the last column consists of axes objects, and the last column is a
    *numinsets* length object ndarray of axes objects.
    """
    fig = plt.figure(**kwargs)
    gs = plt.GridSpec(numrows*numinsets, numcols)

    axes = np.empty([numrows, numcols], dtype=object)
    for i in range(numrows):
        # Add "main" axes...
        for j in range(numcols - 1):
            axes[i, j] = fig.add_subplot(gs[i*numinsets:(i+1)*numinsets, j])

        # Add inset axes...
        for k in range(numinsets):
            m = k + i * numinsets
            axes[i, -1][k] = fig.add_subplot(gs[m, -1])

    return fig, axes

def plot(axes):
    """Recursive plotting function just to put something on each axes."""
    for ax in axes.flat:
        data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100).cumsum()
        try:
            ax.plot(data)
            ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])
        except AttributeError:
            plot(ax)

fig, axes = build_axes_with_insets(2, 4, 3, figsize=(12, 6))
plot(axes)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. GridSpec is what I needed.

Comment: I was wondering if your solution can be adapted to a situation in which we don't know `numinsets` in advance. In the meantime, I did it rearranging `GridSpec`'s output and using `GridSpecFromSubplotSpec`. I will post it anyway to see if there are improvements.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to obtain the same result without setting the number of inset plots in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

nrows = 2
ncols = 4

# changing the shape of GridSpec's output
outer_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows, ncols)
grid = []
for i in range(nrows*ncols):
    grid.append(outer_grid[i])
outer_grid = np.array(grid).reshape(nrows,ncols)

for i in range(nrows):
    inner_grid_1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1,
                subplot_spec=outer_grid[i][0])
    ax = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid_1[0])
    ax.plot(np.random.normal(0,1,50).cumsum())
    fig.add_subplot(ax)

    inner_grid_2 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1,
                subplot_spec=outer_grid[i][1])
    ax2 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid_2[0])
    ax2.plot(np.random.normal(0,1,50).cumsum())
    fig.add_subplot(ax2)

    inner_grid_3 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1,
                subplot_spec=outer_grid[i][2])
    ax3 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid_3[0])
    ax3.plot(np.random.normal(0,1,50).cumsum())
    fig.add_subplot(ax3)

    # this value can be set based on some other calculation depending 
    # on each row
    numinsets = 3 
    inner_grid_4 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(numinsets, 1,
                subplot_spec=outer_grid[i][3])

    # Adding subplots to the last inner grid
    for j in range(inner_grid_4.get_geometry()[0]):
        ax4 = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid_4[j])
        ax4.plot(np.random.normal(0,1,50).cumsum())
        fig.add_subplot(ax4)

# Removing labels
for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed a small improvement. It is possible to remove `plt.Subplot` if we move `fig.add_subplot` (e.g. `ax4 = fig.add_subplot(inner_grid_4[j]); ax4.plot(np.random.normal(0,1,50).cumsum())`)